# passing function as argument to pthread_once

Tags: c

I am trying to use pthread_once to initialize some code. But calling the init_routine() by
{1} causes compile-time warning - warning: passing argument 2 of 'pthread_once' from incompatible pointer type, whereas using
{2} does not give any warning

In file1.c

```
int init_routine (void) {
 // initialize variables
}
```

In file1.h

```
int init_routine(void);
```

Now I include the file1.h in file2.c

In file2.c

```
#include "file1.h"

pthread_once_t prog_inited = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

int start() {
...
pthread_once(&prog_inited, &init_routine);        <-- {1} 
pthread_once(&prog_inited, (void *)init_routine); <-- {2}

...
return 0;
}
```

What is the difference between these?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your declaration of `init_routine`? If it is `extern void init_routine()`, you might need to change it to `extern void init_routine(void)`

Comment: @JosephQuinsey Just edited the question. The `init_routine()` has a return type `int`, and is included in file2.c from file1.h.

Comment: So changing the return type from `int` to `void` may solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answer to updated question) In your header file, you need to change:

```
int init_routine(void);
```

to

```
void init_routine(void);
```

And the call to `pthread_once` doesn't need the `&` before `init_routine`:

```
pthread_once(&prog_inited, init_routine);
```

But what you originally had, namely:

```
pthread_once(&prog_inited, (void *)init_routine);
```

is, as pointed out by cnicutar, not strictly legal C code, but it still should work with almost any compiler in common use today. `gcc`, for example, will only give a warning, and only if you use the `-pedantic` switch.

Comment: Is there another way rather than changing the return type for init_routine?

Comment: Your `(void *)` should be fine. Or a cast `(void (*)(void))`. But if you wanted to be 100% pedantic, you could write a one-line wrapper of the correct type: `void my_init_routine(void) {init_routine();}`. The wrapper could even check the original return value, if it was useful.

Comment: That's a great suggestion to use a wrapper to keep it clean. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for calling pthread_once is:

```
int pthread_once(pthread_once_t *once_control, void (*init_routine)(void));
```

So in your case the call would need to be:

```
pthread_once(&prog_inited, init_routine);
```

The `(void *)` is actually not necessary and wrong because `(void *)` is not a function pointer type and by the standard you are not allowed such a cast!

Comment: But why do I get that compiler warning for {1}. Same warning if I use:  `pthread_once(&prog_inited, init_routine);`